# How can I clamp camera rotation to a specific range?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a camera that I want to restrict the pitch of, as in most first-person games. In this case, the camera is a separate gameobject parented to the player. Here's what I have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotationExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int lookSpeed = 500;

    //main camera, parented to player.
    public GameObject view = new GameObject();

    void Update()
    {
        view.transform.Rotate(-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

        Vector3 viewRotation = view.transform.localEulerAngles;
        viewRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(viewRotation.x, -90, 90);
        view.transform.localEulerAngles.Set(viewRotation.x, 0, 0);

        //print euler angles for debugging
        print("" + view.transform.localEulerAngles);
    }
}
```

With this setup, there doesn't seem to be any effect at all; no clamping and no jittering. `print` shows that once rotation reaches -90 (270 in `print`), the y and z rotation flips from 0 to 180, and the x rotation continues counting down. The inversion also occurs at positive 90, as you would expect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code creates an empty GameObject titled `view`. This GameObject is not assigned a [Camera](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.html) component attached. Is it also not parented to any other GameObjects. As a result, it appears you are attempting to manipulate the position of an empty GameObject.

Unity documentation suggests avoiding direct manipulation of [localEulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html) due to their unpredictive behavior. Instead using [Quaternions](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html) is recommended if you **must** alter localEulerAngles.

You're applying a `Transform.Rotate` in your **Update()** function whilst also using `Transform.localEulerAngles.Set`. Two different means of attempting to set the object's rotation.

The following code can be applied to a script set as a component of the Camera. Or altered, if you wish to manipulate the transform of a child GameObject. Note that your script does not handle rotation around the X-Axis (left - right) movement of the camera, I assumed this is your intended functionality and omitted it from the code:

```
[Header("Inspector Attributes")]
[SerializeField] private float lookSensitivity = 100.0F;
[SerializeField] private float yAxisClampDegrees = 90.0F;

float yRotation;

void Update()
{
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * lookSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

    yRotation -= mouseY;
    yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -yAxisClampDegrees, yAxisClampDegrees);

    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: The gameobject is linked to the camera in the editor, through the drag-and-drop interface. I used localEulerAngles as I saw it suggested in multiple somewhat similar questions on this site, and I wanted to keep the rotation relative to local coordinates as the character itself would rotate for yaw. The unity documentation recommends against ever modifying quaternions directly unless you know exactly what you're doing, so I avoided fumbling around with that and assumed that implied a reasonable alternative exists without using quaternions. I guess Quaternion.Euler was what I was looking for.